# Detecting whether Android device is a phone or a tablet using code

Tags: android, device

I did one application for both mobile and Tablet. Here I want visible few of my contents on Mobile but not in Tablet.

How can I Detect whether Android device is a phone or a tablet while launching my activity.

I Google and find out few suggestions like User -agent..
How can I use it or any other solutions??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you consider a "Mobile" to be? What do you consider a "Tablet" to be? You are better served speaking in terms of specific device characteristics, such as screen size, whether or not the device has telephony capability, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean isTablet (Context context) 
{

    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

this will returne the true if the tablet or false if the mobile

Comment: Only for some definitions of "tablet" and "mobile".

Answer (score 1):

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if (manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)
{
     //It's a tablet
}
else
{
     //It's a phone
}
```

It should works

Answer (score 1):

Well, when it comes to using different resources for different types of screen sizes, the best article is [`"Supporting Multiple Screens"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

My easiest way of detecting device type is to put different values in `strings.xml` for a single key, let's call it `"device_type"`. So in:

1. values -> `strings.xml` I will have `<string name="device_type">smartphone</string>`
2. values-large -> `strings.xml` I will have `<string name="device_type">tablet</string>`
3. values-small -> `strings.xml` I will have `<string name="device_type">small</string>`
4. values-xlarge -> `strings.xml` I will have `<string name="device_type">xlarge</string>`

Having a context, I will read this value and determine what type of device I have.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return hasHoneycomb() && isTab(context);
}
```

With supporting functions

```
     public static boolean hasHoneycomb() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
    }

    public static boolean isTab(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
    }
```